# php get current url & remove word

Tags: php, regex

I have read so much that I have confused myself beyond reason.

What I want (with PHP) is to be able to get the url of the **current page**, and then strip out a specific word and have it displayed on the page.

Example url: `http://domain.com/some/thing/word`

Example output: `http://domain.com/some/thing/`

So far I managed to do one or the other but break things when I try to do it all together.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you post you code?

Comment: you mean this `echo preg_replace('~^(.*\/).*$~', '$1', 'http://domain.com/some/thing/word');`?

Comment: posted it as an answer. [Accept if it seems helpful.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code to remove the last word charcters in your URL,

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('~^(.*\/).*$~', '$1', 'http://domain.com/some/thing/word');
?> //=> http://domain.com/some/thing/
```